# Ext.createDelegate() migrating sencha touch 2 app

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

This line of code is what I have in a Sencha TOuch 1.1 app:

```
var a=Ext.createDelegate(photoSuccess,this,[],true);
```

How the heck I can do the same in Sencha Touch 2? I tried this wit no luck:

```
var a=Ext.bind(photoSuccess,this);
```

Thanks!

Comment: `Ext.bind()` is the successor of `Ext.createDelegate()`. What's the problem with your `Ext.bind()`? What did you expect and what is actually happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A valid representation of

```
var a=Ext.createDelegate(photoSuccess,this,[],true);
```

is

```
var a=Ext.bind(photoSuccess,this,[],true);
```

or just

```
var a=Ext.bind(photoSuccess,this);
```

Here is a working example

```
var photoSuccess = function(foo) {
    console.log('foo', foo);
}

var a = Ext.bind(photoSuccess, window); 

a(1) //outputs: foo 1
```

In other words, your call should work